# Problem with launch file in using urdf with robot_state_publisher tutorial

Tags: ros, urdf, tutorial, robot-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to run topic five of this tutorial but I've a problem with rviz can't work probably.

My roswtf result (with launch file name:state_publisher.launch):

---

```
Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

Found 1 error(s).

ERROR The following packages have rpath issues in manifest.xml:
* r2d2: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
* rosconsole: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
* roscpp: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
* std_msgs: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
* sensor_msgs: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
* tf: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
* rostest: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
* geometry_msgs: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
* message_filters: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"

================================================================================

ROS Master does not appear to be running.
Online graph checks will not be run.
ROS_MASTER_URI is [http://localhost:11311]
```

---

roslaunch state_publisher.launch result:

```
... logging to /home/kitsadapon/.ros/log/3c4387b8-1d12-11e2-82ee-00238b609800/roslaunch-kitsadapon-Joybook-S42-23393.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://kitsadapon-Joybook-S42:41110/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /robot_description
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion

NODES
  /
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/state_publisher)
    state_publisher (r2d2/state_publisher)

auto-starting new master
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[master]: started with pid [23410]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 3c4387b8-1d12-11e2-82ee-00238b609800
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [23423]
started core service [/rosout]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[robot_state_publisher-2]: started with pid [23435]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[state_publisher-3]: started with pid [23452]
```

---

Tutorial link: http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20urdf%20with%20robot_state_publisher

---

Problems with rviz:

- Global Status Error: Fix Frame [/map] does not exist
- Robot Model Status Error: No Transform
- TF Status Warning: NoTransform

Thank you for all answers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46569/problem-with-launch-file-in-using-urdf-with-robot_state_publisher-tutorial/) by [Soda](https://answers.ros.org/users/3104/soda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2012-10-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-23**:
What's the output of `roslaunch state_publisher.launch`? Does it throw any errors? Also, please format shell output and code (mark it and press Ctrl-k).

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-23**:
The output of roslaunch looks ok. What exactly is the error message you get? What's the problem with rviz? Also please provide a link to the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the tutorial:

> Run rviz, choosing odom as your fixed frame. Add a Robot Model and TF.

According to the global status error in rviz, it seems like you didn't select odom as fixed frame in rviz.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Soda](https://answers.ros.org/users/3104/soda/) on 2012-10-23**:
Thank you very much.